# CSS Hover Door opening effect issue on Safari

Tags: css, safari, onhover

According to this link [Repost or flag my own question for migration?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269192/repost-or-flag-my-own-question-for-migration)

I'have to repost my question for a useful answer.

On hover, the doors are supposed to be open, according to the CSS. It works in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and IE but there is no effect on hover in Safari 5.1.7. Where's the problem here? The part of the CSS for this hover is the following:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#cupboard").on("touchstart", function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      $("body").on("touchend", function(e) {
        $("#cupboard").removeClass("hover");
      });

    });
```

```css
 html,
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #C2B3A0;
 }
 /*user-select: none;*/
 /*background: url(bg.jpg);*/
 #cupboard {
   height: 613px;
   width: 617px;
   position: relative;
   left: 35%;
   margin-left: -112px;
   top: 24px;
   bottom: 31px;
   perspective: 500;
   background: url(bg.png);
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: 95%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 #cupboard img {
   position: inherit;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 62px;
   margin-top: 82px;
 }
 #cupboard .door#left {
   zoom: .6;
   position: absolute;
   width: 512px;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(dl.jpg);
   transition: transform 1s ease;
   transform: rotateY(0);
 }
 #cupboard .door#right {
   zoom: .6;
   position: absolute;
   width: 517px;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(dr.jpg);
   transition: transform 1s ease;
   transform: rotateY(0);
 }
 #cupboard .door#left {
   transform-origin: top left;
   left: 0;
 }
 #cupboard .door#right {
   transform-origin: top right;
   right: 0;
 }
 #cupboard:hover #left,
 #cupboard.hover #left {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
   transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 #cupboard:hover #right,
 #cupboard.hover #right {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
   transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cupboard">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
      <img src="f.jpeg" alt="facebook" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
      <img src="t.jpeg" alt="twiter" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com">
      <img src="l.png" alt="linkedin" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.wordpress.com">
      <img src="w.jpg" alt="wordpress" />
    </a>

    <div class="door" id="left"></div>

    <div class="door" id="right"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the sreenshot of output page:-

**Before hover :-**

[image]

**After hover :-**

[image]

**Screenshot of Safari**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d), safari needs the `-webkit-` prefix to work. Also you don't have any units after your perspective length.

Edit from your comment for completeness:

Also need to use `-webkit-transition: all 1ms ease;`

Comment: @perterjb
As you said, I used
-webkit-perspective: 500px; 
perspective: 500px;

now it show some effect but not same as chrome, doors are open but it come to center not on the side borders.

Comment: @akash Unfortunately I don't have safari at work so I can't see what you are talking about.  Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @akash Oh I think I see... you need to put the prefix on the `transform-origin` property, too

Comment: @perterjb I think transition is not working. And now I'am able to see door on side border by changing in -webkit-transform-origin. But still have problem with transition. It opens suddenly.

Comment: @perterjb Thanks for your help. Lastly, I put -webkit-transition: all 1ms ease;
And now its working

Comment: No problem. I've put up your edit with some edits. I just didn't want to take credit for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

Css transition codes for each of browsers is different and you should set them for all browsers.
Please visit to css tricks site or w3school site for standard sintax of it for safari browser.